# AudioServicesPlaySystemSounds and Notification Sounds Have Stopped Working

Tags: ios, audio, system-sounds

All of a sudden, none of the sounds in the iOS app I'm developing (with Swift) are working. This goes for the AudioServicesPlaySystemSounds calls as well as notification sounds with a custom .aiff file. No sounds. They were working great until just recently. (not sure when I first noticed. It's been a few weeks)

Did Apple change something? I can't find any documentation for sound implementation changing.

Here's what I've tried:

- I'm not in silent mode/DND and volume is up
- I tried the AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion version without success
- I've tried setting device volume to 1.0 with MPVolumeView without success
- I tried implementing SpriteKit's sound functions without success
- Tried refactoring with AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url) implementation without success

Comment: What platform is this? Is the problem only with one device? Is the problem only with one app? Please put all those important details in your question.

Comment: Sorry @HangarRash, edited now. It's happening across all iOS devices and only with the app I'm working on. I haven't changed anything dealing with sound.

Comment: Is your code in source control (git)? Rollback to a version of the app that used to work. Then look at all code changes since to see what might be the cause.